# How to get typescript type completion for Pixi 6 native module?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, pixi.js

I am building a PixiJS game with native ES modules, without using a bundler such as Parcel or Rollup.

I am also loading PixiJS as a native module, I found the module in `node_modules/pixi.js/dist/esm/pixi.js`. I can now use:

```
import { Sprite } from './pixi.mjs'
```

The only problem is that the accompanying `index.d.ts` file is not recognised by VS Code (I found this file in `node_modules/pixi.js/index.d.ts`), so type checking for PixiJS doesn't work correctly, even though the code DOES run!

My folder structure is super simple. There is not even a `package.json`.

```
index.html
js/app.js
js/pixi.mjs
js/pixi.mjs.map
js/index.d.ts
```

How can I force VS Code to read the `index.d.ts` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with this approach.

## Declaration files are missing

First of all, if you look at the types installed by pixi.js in `node_modules/pixi.js/index.d.ts` you will find that it is **mostly empty**, and
it references external packages starting with `@pixi`. This is due to the mono-repo approach in the [pixi project](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/tree/dev/packages).

You will only fulfill those references if these packages are installed as **npm modules** (which happens automatically after installing pixi.js) and for which you need a `package.json` so that TypeScript finds them by their package name.

## Link between imported classes and types

Secondly, VS Code (or better said, the TypeScript engine) is not capable of relating the files `pixi.mjs` and `index.d.ts` once they are moved out of the `node_modules` folder. Although the classes are named the same (Sprite, Container, etc.), TypeScript cannot safely conclude that they refer to the same thing.

This workflow is automatic when using npm thanks to the `types` property in `node_modules/pixi.js/package.json`. As an alternative, you can rename the file `index.d.ts` to `pixi.mjs.d.ts` and TypeScript will relate them by file name.

This is the folder structure that TypeScript can understand:

```
index.html
js/app.js
js/pixi.mjs
js/pixi.mjs.d.ts
js/pixi.mjs.map
```

## TypeScript error detection in JS files

Finally, the previous fixes **will only provide type inference** but no error detection in js files. If you want VS Code to report errors, you need to create a `tsconfig.json` file with the following settings:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "checkJs": true,
  },
  "include": ["js/*.js"],
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, that clarified a lot! I actually have a `jsconfig.json` that contains the same things as your `tsconfig.json`. But I'm still not clear on how to solve the issue. Should I include `node_modules` in my project just for type checking? But not `import` from there? Because I don't want to upload the whole `node_modules` to the live website.

Comment: When I rename `types.d.ts` to `pixi.mjs.d.ts` it is indeed recognised by VS Code, but as you say, it doesn't work because the types are referenced from `node_modules`.

Comment: You can follow your current solution if that suits your need. Having the `node_modules` in the suggested solution would merely serve the purpose of providing the type declarations. In other words, only needed in the development environment. For production you can skip the .d.ts files.

Comment: @Kokodoko I'm a bit unclear, did this answer actually solve your issue? I think I'm dealing with something similar and this answer explains some things but are you saying this involved editing the file names directly in `node_modules`?

Comment: @MattTreichel No, I abandoned this approach, because the only way to get type checking to work is to include the whole `node_modules` folder with PIXI in your project. And once you have that, you might as well get PIXI itself also from that folder. It makes no sense to use `node_modules` only for the `.d.ts` file.